# Corrupt debug symbols found from build generated from XCode14, but it works fine using XCode13

Tags: ios, swift, xcode13, xcode14, dsym

Recently, I had to migrate a project to XCode-14 due to mandatory compliance of Appstore starting April 2023.

Now the issue is that, debug symbols generated from build using XCode14 shows corrupted, thus, Firebase is unable to process our crashes. However, it works from XCode13.

can anyone help me find the solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check  the following build settings ```Generate Debug Symbols = Yes```,  ```Strip Debug Symbols During Copy = No``` and  ```Debug Information Format =  DWARF with dSYM File```

Comment: @udi checked those settings, all are same as mentioned above.
Any other causes?